# JS: Import json file utf8

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I use react-intl to provide localized strings for my web application. When I import the german language file it is not encoded using utf8.

```
import messages_en from './localization/en.json';
import messages_de from './localization/de.json';

setMessageProperty(lang) {
    console.info("switch language to " + lang);
    console.info(messages_de);
}
```

The json object I then receive has elements of this form:
delete: "L�schen"
but what I want is this:
delete: "Löschen"

Comment: Are the .json files saved in UTF8 format? Can you see the contents correctly if you open them in a text editor?

Comment: Yes, both notepad++ and visual studio render them correct

Comment: Try checking what the actual encoding is and converting to UTF8 if it's not

Comment: Do you change font in your page/app?